# Функции в JavaScript, Прототипы

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. Что значит "._" здесь? Знаю что прототип объекта. Можете объяснить логику работы?

```
Data.prototype._getRandomPosition = function() {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ничего, это обозначение сделано программистом для других программистов, что этот метод приватный.

Comment: То есть я могу просто написать так? Data.prototype.getRandomPosition = function() {}

Comment: @Timur, да, ты можешь просто написать так.